# Implement view like facebook image viewer - android

Tags: android, animation, pinchzoom

I need to implement an activity to view image with zoom in-out controls, and it can be closed by dragging up or down [like facebook, or google photos].

here is link to [facebook animation](https://youtu.be/dOFvqyM1lYE) "drag to close"

Comment: Have you found a solution ?